# np.where: and condition over multiple columns of a 2d array

Tags: numpy

I would like to use np.where on a array (arr) in order to retrieve the indices corresponding to the following condition: first column value must be **1**, third column value must be **two**, here is my code so far:

```
arr = np.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [1,0,2],
    [0,0,0],
    [1,0,2]
    ])


print(np.where(arr[:,0]==1 and arr[:,2]==2))
```

But it produces this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue of operator precedence, you need to use parentheses:

```
np.where((arr[:,0]==1)&(arr[:,2]==2))
```

A more generic method (imagine you have 20 columns to compare) would be to use:

```
np.where((arr[:,[0,2]]==[1,2]).all(1))
```

output: `(array([1, 3]),)`

Comment: thx, but can you please tell what the '1' in **all(1)** stands for exactly ?

Comment: @RandomFellow https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html

Comment: it means all values per row (axis=1) must be True to have True.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little change would help :

```
    arr = np.array([
    [0,0,0],
    [1,0,2],
    [0,0,0],
    [1,0,2]
    ])

#print(np.where(arr[:,0]==1 and arr[:,2]==2))
print(np.where(arr[:,0]==1) , np.where(arr[:,2]==0))
```

Output :

```
array([1, 3], dtype=int64),) (array([0, 2], dtype=int64)
```